Linear transformation definition redundancy?
In Hubbard and Hubbard, the authors define a linear transformation with two properties:
(1) $T(v+w)=T(v)+T(w)$
(2) $T(cv)=cT(v)$
My question is this: isn't property 2 redundant? For instance, since $T(2v)=T(v+v)$, by property 1 it would obviously have to be $T(v)+T(v)=2T(v)$. Is there something about the definition of transformations that makes it not so obvious that $T(v)+T(v)$ equals $2T(v)$?

That argument only works when $c$ is an integer

what about $T(\frac{1}{2}v)=\frac{1}{2} T(v)$?

@SujitBhattacharyya would have actually followed from property (1) alone since we would have $T(v)=T(\frac{1}{2}v + \frac{1}{2}v) = T(\frac{1}{2}v)+T(\frac{1}{2}v) = 2T(\frac{1}{2}v)$ and so dividing by $2$ we have $\frac{1}{2}T(v)=T(\frac{1}{2}v)$.  We might have been safe for rational numbers in general if this were the field in question...

@Notograptus If $T$ is defined over a real vector space, you can deduce that $T(cv) = cT(v)$ will hold for rational numbers $c$, but not that the statement holds for arbitrary real $c$. If $T$ is a continuous linear transformation (at any point within the vector space), then $T(cv) = cT(v)$ must hold for real $c$.

@Notograptus By the way, the condition that $T(v + w) = T(v) + T(w)$ is sometimes called Cauchy's functional equation

Yes, from $T(v+w)=T(v)+T(w)$ for each two vectors $v$ and $w$, you can deduce that $T(2v)$ is always equal to $2T(v)$. However, it does not follow that, say, $T(\pi v)=\pi T(v)$.
